# From QStringList to ListViewModel in qml

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml, qstringlist

I have followed [this example](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtquick-models-stringlistmodel-example.html) with some changes  to show QStringList in ListView. So, I have a `QStringList` in MyClass.cpp and I want to show those items in ListView in MyDialog.qml

////main.cpp////

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    MyClass *strListView=new MyClass;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("strListView", strListView);
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

//// MyClass.h////

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QHash>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>

class MyClass: public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyClass(QObject *parent=nullptr);

private:
    QStringList str;
```

////MyClass.cpp////

```
MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel {parent}
{
str.append("name1");
str.append("name2");
str.append("name3");

    QQuickView view;
    QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("strListView", QVariant::fromValue(str));

    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:MyDialog.qml"));
}
```

In qml I have 2 qml files: main.qml and MyDialog.qml
////MyDialog.qml////

```
...
    Rectangle
    {
id:recList
width:100
height:50

ListView
        {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            anchors.fill: parent
Text {
                text: modelData
            }
}
```

It doesnt show anything and I get the warning:  `ReferenceError: modelData is not defined.`

Comment: If you want to create your own subclass of [QAbstractListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html) take are look at this example in Qt Doc  -> [Using C++ Models with Qt Quick Views](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qabstractitemmodel-subclass)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the usage inside your Qml Component should be somthing like this:

```
ListView {
     model: myModel;

     Text {
          text: displayRole
     }
}
```

Inside your C++ Component you should expose the model to the QML file:

```
QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
ctxt->setContextProperty(myModel,this);
```

Finally, you need to map the `Qt::ItemDataRole` by setting `setRoleNames` on your model, like:

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> map={{Qt::ItemDataRole::DisplayRole, "displayRole"}};
this->setRoleNames(map);
```

I also think, that it is not really necessary to derive from `QAbstractListModel` for such an easy use case. Just use `QStandardItemModel` and you are home free.